# Is there a way to show bitmap data in html image tag?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to show bitmap image data in an HTML element?

For example, you have a regular image that points to a source file like this:

```
<img src="myImage.png" width="100" height="100" />
```

Is there something like this:

```
<img width="100" height="100">
     <data>ABCDEF...</data>
</img>
```

Where data would be bitmap data or something similar? And if possible if you know if it's recommended or supported in major browsers?

Comment: Please don't change an old question to something completely different, especially if it already has answers. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: OK. I added a new question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs):

```
<img src="data:image/bmp,ABCDEF..." width="100" height="100" />
```

If you encoded the data in base64, it could look like this:

```
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,BASE64DATAGOESHERE..." width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Data URIs have there own pitfalls and should be [taken with a grain of salt](http://www.mobify.com/blog/css-sprites-vs-data-uris-which-is-faster-on-mobile/)!

Comment: 8 years after posting it, your example here sorted our issue out - thanks.

Comment: For reference here archive of the link @nietonfir mention in his comment [taken with a grain of salt](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404090840/http://www.mobify.com/blog/css-sprites-vs-data-uris-which-is-faster-on-mobile/)!