# How to parse to image content-type: image/bmp received from server?

Tags: javascript, image

I receive image from server with `Content-Type: image/bmp`, and need to show it on front.

I use `react.js` for client side, and I don't know how to parse what I'm receiving.

I tried to use `Base64` parser and put the result to `img.src` but it didn't help.

```
let { data } = yield call(axios, requestConfig1);
data = Base64.decode(data);

const img = new Image();
img.src = data;
```

Also tried using data directly:

```
img.src = `data:image/bmp;base64,${file}`;
```

Didn't help. I see (unknown) in src propertry of img tag.

I want to show result as img tag.

I see respose in code like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried 'data:image/bmp;base64,BASE64DATAGOESHERE...'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to show bitmap data in html image tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369334/is-there-a-way-to-show-bitmap-data-in-html-image-tag)

Comment: is your API returning Base64 encoded data?. You have mentioned `'Content-Type: image/bmp`, then the API might be returning an image binary. In that case, you can set the API URL directly in image src. If you don't want to expose the URL then you need to encode your image data to Base64 and set the src as data url `data:image/bmp;base64,${file}`

Comment: @ajai Jothi yes, good idea, but this is /POST request that returns me this image. And this API isn't mine, i can't edit it :(

Comment: @VitaliSkripka sounds like your API is not returning a Base64 image, it is returning the actual image binary. So, you have to encode it to Base64 `file = btoa(data)` then `img.src = \`data:image/bmp;base64,${file}\``. Remove `data = Base64.decode(data);` line

Comment: @ajai Jothi  Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: @VitaliSkripka would you able to paste the screenshot of the response?

Comment: @ajai Jothi added in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the screenshot, your API is returning an image binary, so you should encode the raw image data to base64 string.

**Note:** I hope your `requestConfig1` has the `requestType:'blob'`

**Solution 1:** [Base64](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript_base64.html#.XLfnzZNKjRY) library

```
let { data } = yield call(axios, requestConfig1);
data = Base64.encode(data)

const img = new Image();
img.src = `data:image/bmp;base64,${data}`;
```

**Solution 2:** with `btoa`

> using [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) to avoid 'characters outside of the Latin1 range' error. This feature was removed from the web standard but still supported by all the browsers.

```
let { data } = yield call(axios, requestConfig1);
data = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));

const img = new Image();
img.src = `data:image/bmp;base64,${data}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
img.src = `data:image/bmp;base64,${file}`;
```

Comment: Yes, didn't help